# How to get SIMD code from C code

Tags: c, simd

I am working on a m/c `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v2 @ 2.00GHz` It supports SSE4.2.

I have written C code to perform XOR operation over string bits. But I want to write corresponding SIMD code and check for performance improvement. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LENGTH 10

unsigned char xor_val[LENGTH];

void oper_xor(unsigned char *r1, unsigned char *r2)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        xor_val[i] = (unsigned char)(r1[i] ^ r2[i]);
    printf("%d",xor_val[i]);
    }
}

int main() {

    int i;
    time_t start, stop;
    double cur_time;
    start = clock();
    oper_xor("1110001111", "0000110011");
    stop = clock();
    cur_time = ((double) stop-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Time used %f seconds.\n", cur_time / 100);
    for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
        printf("%d",xor_val[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling and running a sample code I am getting output shown below. Time is 00 here but in actual project it is consuming sufficient time.

```
gcc xor_scalar.c -o xor_scalar
pan88: ./xor_scalar
1110111100 Time used 0.000000 seconds.
1110111100
```

How can I start writing a corresponding SIMD code for SSE4.2

Comment: What does your compiler manual say? The question as posed has nothing to do with the C language and everything to do with your compiler implementation.

Comment: Do you honestly expect to be able to time an `xor` on 10 bytes by calling `clock()`? What kind of resolution do you expect? The function call is probably slower than the `xor`. Also, why do you think you need to explicitly write SIMD-code for this? The code is entirely trivial to vectorize, and any decent compiler will do so automatically, especially if you `restrict` the arguments to avoid aliasing.

Comment: If you want to write SIMD code, write it in assembly. FASM is a pretty good assembler.

Comment: @EOF Actually, I am using 128 bits. Also, I need to count number of 1s in the result  xor_val , which will be time consuming so need to use popcnt.

Answer (score 4):

The Intel Compiler and any OpenMP compiler support `#pragma simd` and `#pragma omp simd`, respectively. These are your best bet to get the compiler to do SIMD codegen for you. If that fails, you can use intrinsics or, as a means of last resort, inline assembly.

Note the the `printf` function calls will almost certainly interfere with vectorization, so you should remove them from any loops in which you want to see SIMD.

Comment: I went through https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/512635   and https://www.cilkplus.org/tutorial-pragma-simd tutorial. It uses icc compiler cant we use gcc compiler with #pragma simd to generate simd code

Comment: I don't know about GCC support for Cilk's `pragma simd`.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2014-02/msg00240.html for some commentary.  I would recommend instead that one follow the recommendation to use `pragma omp simd` with `-fopenmp-simd` when desiring SIMD from GCC in code that doesn't use any other OpenMP features, because it relies on a portable API (OpenMP4).